# Asterisk Sip Reachable timeout

Tags: asterisk, sip

Sometime in my sip accounts occurs network problem and generates "UnReachable" event.

```
[2020-04-27 16:57:56] NOTICE[2949] chan_sip.c: Peer '323' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 6
```

I also see it in log files. I have 2 question about this situation.

1. After how many second Asterisk generate this event when can not access to sip account?
2. Exist some parametr change this reachable timeout second?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at:

```
qualifyfreq=60 = default value is 60 sec
qualifygap=100
```

this works if:

```
qualify=yes|4000 = 4000 ms
```